# Extract a string after certain word Presto SQL

Tags: sql, regex, presto

I'm trying to build a Regex Expression to extract a string after a certain string. The full string I have is:

```
Your full name (TL submitting form): XXX
What is your vendor location?: Phoenix
```

The work a want to extract is the vendor location, in the case above would be *Phoenix*.

I'm using the code below:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(description_text, '(What is your vendor location\?\:)(.*?)(?=)'))) AS vendor_location
```

The results using this code is:

```
Task ID.   Date          Vendor location
90836966 2021-05-14. What is your vendor location?:
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(description_text, 'What is your vendor location\?:\s*(.+)', 1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YfiI1O/1).

The `What is your vendor location\?:\s*(.+)` regex matches

- `What is your vendor location\?:` - a `What is your vendor location?:` literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The last `1` argument extracts the Group 1 value as a result of the function.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you =D